# Как делать оптимизацию под разные экраны мобильных тачскринов?

Tags: веб-программирование, android, iphone

Здравствуйте. 
Как делать оптимизацию под разные экраны мобильных тачскринов (андроидов, айфонов)?

Answer (score 4):

В Android это довольно неплохо документировано. Как я понимаю из контекста речь идет об картинках - тут все довольно просто. Надо готовить в общем случае 4 различных изображения для различных девайсов (в зависимости от dpi):

1. Низкое разрешение ~120 dpi
2. Среднее разрешение ~160 dpi
3. Высокое разрешение ~240 dpi
4. Очень высокое разрешение ~320 dpi

Все эти ресурсы кладутся в папки drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi тогда ОС будет брать их "само" в зависимости от разрещения устройства.

Более подробно [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

Под разные разрешения экранов (и размеров соответственно) в android есть специальные ресурс-квалификаторы размеров. Достаточно в нужный каталог сохранить ресурсы (изображения, файлы лэйаутов ...) и система сама определит какой тип ресурса загрузить в зависимости от текущего дисплея или ориентации.
Подробнее можно [почитать на офф.сайте](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Про андроид не в курсе, в айфоне вставляются две версии картинки - sample.png и sample@2x.png и для ретины автоматом подставляется @2x картинки, для iPad делаются отдельные xib-бы

Ретина -дисплей iPhone начиная с 4-ой версии, в нем больше разрешение (960х640 против 480х320 у 2G, 3G и 3GS) и для него соответственно создаются картинки с таким разрешением и именем name@2x.png, проект также включает в себя картинки для старых моделей с именем name.png, в коде используются именно они, а что именно подгружать решает сама система. Xib - это специальный файл, в котором хранится внешний вид форм приложения (они View называются вообще-то, но я обозвал их формами чтобы не путаться), т.к. у iPad вообще другое соотношение сторон, то для него делают свою компоновку и помещают её в отдельный файл (кстати, так же локализуют картинки - делают разные файлы для разных языков), сделать это можно средствами среды насколько я помню

Comment: Если не тяжело, дайте, пожалуйста более развернутый ответ и без слов типа "ретины", "xib-бы" и т.д. Мне эти слова не понятны.

Comment: Сделал, но как вы что-то делать собираетесь если не в курсе что это такое?

Comment: Я делаю приложение для Web на JavaScript. Я не работаю с программами. Поэтому мне неизвестно что там и как внутри. Но в общем мне идея ясна. Подождем еще предложений. Может, есть какой-то универсальный метод для любых телефонов. Может, что-то еще.

Comment: Да, Obj-C. Если веб, тогда наверное мой ответ немного не по адресу, не увидел тега веб.